# How can I get data from JavaScript code in a .NET WebBrowser control running on mono?

Tags: .net, mono, webbrowser-control

The WebBrowser control was designed to be able to make calls from JavaScript to .NET (and pass data) via the ObjectForScripting property (on the .NET side) and the window.external object on the JavaScript side.

However, this is not implemented in mono.

What are my options for getting data and/or making calls from the JavaScript side to the .NET side?

(Mono does support communication in the other direction via the Document.InvokeScript method.)

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I found a way:  [Mono and window.external](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084850/mono-and-window-external/1847888#1847888)

**Upodate:**   Crap. In mono, setting location.url causes the browser control's Document property to clear, which makes it impossible to later call back into script using Document.InvokeScript.

Comment: This occurs even if you cancel the navigation event, which seems to not actually cancel anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way:  You can set the title of the document in JavaScript and monitor the browser.Document.Title in .NET.  Once you have processed the command in .NET, set the title back to empty string so you don't process it again.

Sure, it's a hack, but that's life with mono.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using JQuery.  The javascript can call a web service exposed in your application to pass data back and forth.

Comment: Wouldn't my app need an embedded HTTP server for that?